# How to insert HTMLTableRowElement into a Table Body?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, frontend

I've taken a look at [table](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) and table body methods, and it does not mention how to insert a `HTMLTableRowElement`. Anyone know a nice way to insert a `HTMLTableRowElement` into the table body?

```
const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
// Only inserts an empty row
// Want to insert a HTMLTableRowElement that I've parsed using jsdom
tbody.insertRow();
```

**EDIT**:
With guidance @frontend_dev, it looks like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) is not using native DOM elements. So the solution may look something like the follow:

```
let rows_rep = '';
jsdom.env(html_with_tr, function(err, w) {
  rows_rep = w.document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].outerHTML; 
}

const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
const newRow = tbody.insertRow();
newRow.innerHTML = rows_rep;
```

Comment: If you have a prerendered `<tr>` dom element, why not just use `appendChild` or `insertBefore`?

Comment: I tried that but it says `parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`. Perhaps jsdom isn't using native DOM elements? To give more context, I am using [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to get elements from another page, then trying to inject those elements into my current page.

Comment: Don't know jsdom, but at a first glance, yeah it seems it is not native DOM. So the only option you might have is using a string representation and then user innerHTML on the <tr> element you created with for example insertRow()

Comment: Yup looks like that it what I had to do. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use jsdom for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an HTML string containing the row you want to add, you can get that row without `jsdom` and append it to a table in the current document:

```js
// Sample HTML string:
var html = `<html>
<body>
   <h1>my title</h1>
   <table><tr><td>dynamicly added row</td></tr></table>
   <p>other text in here</p>
</body>
</html>`;

// Create in-memory element and load HTML into it:
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = html;
// Get the row element out of it, and append it:
var tr = span.querySelector('tr');
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
tbody.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table border=1>
   <tr><td>existing row</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. You are right jsdom is not needed. Initially I was looking for something similar to BeautifulSoup, but this way is much cleaner.